# Sampling where number of samples per cluster varies in R

Tags: r, sample

I have a dataframe,

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),score=c(1,3,5,7,3,4,7,1,2,6,3),cluster=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3))
```

I also have a set of cluster IDs and the number of samples I'd like from each cluster,

```
sample_sizes<-data.frame(cluster=c(1,2,3),samples=c(1,3,2))
```

I would like to have a samples dataframe consisting of samples selected according to the number of samples specified in the `sample_sizes` dataframe.

For instance, the following table would be a potential result:

```
id     score    cluster
2      3        1
3      4        2
5      3        2
6      4        2
9      2        3
11     3        3
```

I have looked at  using the following using `dplyr`:

```
df2<-merge(df,sample_sizes)
df3<-df2 %>%
    group_by(cluster) %>%
    sample_n(samples)
```

but receive an error.

Is there a best method for doing this?  A solution that could scale with larger numbers of clusters and samples would be ideal.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

We may use `map2_df` along with `split`:

```
map2_df(split(df, df$cluster), sample_sizes$samples, sample_n)
#   id score cluster
# 1  1     1       1
# 2  4     7       2
# 3  5     3       2
# 4  3     5       2
# 5  7     7       3
# 6  9     2       3
```

`split(df, df$cluster)` gives a list of data frames, one for each cluster, then `map2_df` applies `sample_n` to each cluster, just like you intended, and binds the resulting data frames into one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `tidyr::nest()` and `purrr::map2`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% group_by(cluster) %>% nest() %>% 
       left_join(sample_sizes) %>% mutate(samp=map2(data,samples,sample_n)) %>% 
       select(cluster,samples,samp) %>% unnest()

Joining, by = "cluster"
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  cluster samples    id score
    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1       1       1     1     1
2       2       3     5     3
3       2       3     6     4
4       2       3     4     7
5       3       2     8     1
6       3       2    10     6
```